# Expressing decimals as a sequence of nested intervals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I = [0,1]$ and $t\in[0,1]$

Define: $A_{p}(t) = \frac{p}{4}+\frac{1}{4}t,\quad$ $p\in\{0,1,2,3\}$

Let write $t$ in terms of the quaternary system

$t = 0.t_1t_2\ldots t_{n-1}t_n \ldots,\quad t_i\in\{0,1,2,3\}$

In my book there is stated that

$t = \lim_{n\to\infty} A_{t_1}A_{t_2}\ldots A_{t_n}(I)$

The thing i don't understand is the order in which the functions are evaluated. Why not this way:

$t = \lim_{n\to\infty} A_{t_n}A_{t_{n-1}}\ldots A_{t_1}(I)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the decimal version $A_p= \frac{p+t}{10}$.
Given a value $t=0.t_1t_2t_3...$, what this function does is add the digit $p$ to give $p+t=p.t_1t_2t_3...$, and then divide by $10$ to shift the decimal point to the left to give $A_p(t)=0.pt_1t_2t_3...$. So the function $A_p$ inserts the digit $p$ on the left end, just behind the decimal point.

So if you use these functions $A_p$ to build a decimal number, you are inserting digits on the left hand side, and when you stop the last one you inserted is the left-most digit. Therefore, to build $0.t_1t_2...t_n$ you will have to end with $t_1$ (and hence start with $t_n$).

The functions in the question do the same but in base $4$.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you